# How to fetch Product options label on Add To Cart button click?

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart

I am trying to get the configurable product selected options value, option titles on clicking the Add to cart button.
From the post content, I get the `option_id` but : How we can fetch the and Option Titles.
For eg :  (See Screenshot for reference )

[image])

I have ten text fields and two select fields : So on submit I need can get the values entered by the user but I am not able to fetch the titles of the text fields or the titles of the selected options.

**Note :** I have used "bss dependtent custom option" extension for creating the options.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem with the following code, If anybody face the same issue you can try this method:

```
/*  SHOWING SELECTED CUSTOM OPTIONS ON AJAX CART POPUP  */
        $items = $this->_cart->getItems();
        foreach($items as $product) {
        $options = $product->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product->getProduct());
            if ($options)
            {
                if (isset($options['options']))
                {
                    $result = $options['options'];
                }
                    if ($i == $len - 1) { // get only last product details
                        foreach($result as $key =>$value){
                            echo "<strong>".$resultoption = $value['label'].'</strong>';
                            echo "<p> ".$resultoption =  $value['value'].'</p><br>';
                        }
                    }
            }
            else{
                echo "NO OPTIONS";  // nothing here
            }
            $i++;
        }

        /* SHOWING SELECTED CUSTOM OPTIONS ON AJAX CART POPUP */ ` :
```

Thanks!